# Can't mount glusterfs after relocating disks

Tags: glusterfs

I had a working gluster installation runnning on ubuntu 14.04. Now I have reconnected the sata ports and the gluster brick is now mounted from the other port. It is available:

```
/dev/sda1                    236M   38M  186M  17% /boot
/dev/sdc1                     20G  7.2G   12G  39% /data/gluster
/dev/sdb1                    7.8G  2.9G  4.5G  39% /data/mysql
```

Unfortunatelly I can not mount it anymore:

~sudo mount gs1:volume1 /data/nfs

nothing happens, cursor stays in blank line. I have to cancel with ctrl c or wait until I get a timout:

```
node1:~sudo mount gs1:volume1 /data/nfs
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

volume info

```
Volume Name: volume1
Type: Replicate
Volume ID: 92d9adb8-756b-4138-87a8-23237d21688f
Status: Started
Number of Bricks: 1 x 2 = 2
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: gs1:/data/gluster/brick
Brick2: gs2:/data/gluster/brick
```

There is nothing in the logs. The IP Adress of the gluster servers are in /etc/hosts and I can ping them.

How could I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Gluster-Server on node 2 was not running and the entry for mounting the volume in /etc/fstab contained the startup option to failover to gs2. Somehow this prevents gs1 from mounting the drive. once gs2 is live, the share can be mounted from gs1.